# Is there an r package for correcting for multiple testing in GLM's, specifically for relative risk or risk difference?

Tags: r, glm, confidence-interval

In my study I am looking at sex differences in the efficacy of biologicals (=type of medicine) in patients with axial spondyloarthritis. I am looking at different 7 different outcomes (disease activity scores) at time 6, 12 and 24 months. I am using a GLM with binomial family to calculate relative risk and risk difference. I wish to make the confidence intervals broader, since I wish to correct for multiple testing.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is a small representative dataset and the code I ran:

```
dat <- structure(list(gender = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), age_std = structure(c(-0.467384378359854, 
-0.623520001679169, 0.703632796535007, -0.935791248317799, -1.16999468329677, 
1.32817528981227, -1.16999468329677, 0.235225926577062, -0.857723436658141, 
-0.389316566700197, -0.467384378359854, -0.31124875504054, -1.24806249495643, 
-1.09192687163711, -0.623520001679169, -1.40419811827574, -1.79453717657403, 
-1.71646936491437, -1.87260498823369, -1.09192687163711), .Dim = c(20L, 
1L)), bio_drug_start_year_centered = c(-6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -9, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0), country = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CH", "CZ", "DK", "ES", "IS", "IT", "NL", 
"NO", "PT", "RO", "SE", "SF", "SI", "TR", "UK"), class = "factor"), 
    bio_drug_start_year = c(2007, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2004, 
    2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2016, 2015, 2013, 2015, 
    2013, 2013, 2014, 2013), asdas_crp_cii_6month = c(1, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)), na.action = structure(c(`114174` = 2755L, 
`116484` = 2770L, `231118` = 3050L), class = "omit"), row.names = c("463", 
"7729", "7756", "8306", "8324", "128", "8440", "8450", "8663", 
"8809", "8840", "8857", "9020", "9033", "9101", "9324", "9377", 
"9523", "9702", "9718"), class = "data.frame")
    
rr = rd = numeric()
for( i in 1: 1e3){
  logmod = glm( asdas_crp_cii_6month ~ gender + country + age_std + bio_drug_start_year_centered, 
                family = 'binomial', data = dat[sample(1:nrow(dat),nrow(dat),replace=T),])
  summary(logmod)
  dat.1 = dat.0 = dat
  dat.1$gender = 1
  dat.0$gender = 0
  p1 = predict(logmod, newdata = dat.1, 'response' )
  p0 = predict(logmod, newdata = dat.0, 'response' )
  rr[i] = mean(p1)/mean(p0)
  rd[i] = mean(p1)-mean(p0)
}
twosidep<-function(data, test = 0){
  p1<-sum(data>test)/length(data)
  p2<-sum(data<test)/length(data)
  p<-min(p1,p2)*2
  return(p)
}
m = rbind(c(mean(rr), quantile(rr, c(0.025, 0.975)), twosidep(rr, test = 1) ),
          c(mean(rd), quantile(rd, c(0.025, 0.975)), twosidep(rd) ))
rownames(m) = c('rr', 'rd')
colnames(m) = c('Estimate', 'Lower CI', 'Upper CI', 'p-value')
m
```

Here is the output of the code

```
     Estimate   Lower CI  Upper CI p-value
rr  0.6337688  0.1612215 1.1929914    0.25
rd -0.3050054 -0.5731631 0.1239957    0.25
```

**Question: How can I increase these confidence intervals with the bonferroni correction method?**

Comment: Rather than trying to find a function, you first need to determine if there is a statistical method that's appropriate for your data to accomplish what you want. You should first ask for statistical help at [stats.se]. Once you know what method is appropriate, it should be easier to search how to perform that action in R. You need to know exactly how you want to correct for multiple testing.

Comment: I should have added that in the question. I wish to use bonferroni correction.